# Why does eps fail in a matrix when used with realmax

Tags: matlab, double, precision

See

```
>> eps([1 2 0.00001; (realmax('double')-10) realmin('double') realmax('single')])

ans =

    1.192093e-07    2.384186e-07    9.094947e-13
             NaN    1.401298e-45    2.028241e+31
```

However,

```
>> eps(realmax('double') - 10)

ans =

     1.99584030953472e+292
```

I would have expected the `NaN` in example 1 to take the answer value from example 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when you create the following array:

```
[(realmax('double')-10) realmin('double') realmax('single')]
%//    Inf    0    3.402823e+38
```

The first entry is infinity and by definition, `eps(Inf) == NaN`.

Why does this happen, well `realmax('single')` returns a single-precision number and `realmax('double')` returns a double precision number.

> `REALMAX('single')` returns the largest finite floating point number in
>       IEEE single precision.

When you concatenate the two, MATLAB [downcasts the entire array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/valid-combinations-of-unlike-classes.html) to a `single` precision number which obviously causes the `realmax('double')-10` to excede the range of the datatype and it becomes infinity.

```
class(realmax('double'))
%// double

class(realmax('single'))
%// single

class([(realmax('double')-10) realmin('double') realmax('single')])
%// single
```

When you call `eps(realmax('double') - 10)` by itself, the very large `double` is actually a `double` and `eps` returns the expected epsilon.

Comment: to be precise I had no idea that `realmin` and `realmax` do not return double values.

Comment: The concatenation conversion table is given [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/valid-combinations-of-unlike-classes.html).  And a possible [explanation of "why"](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/18222-arithmetic-promotion-floating-point-to-integer#answer_24526) appears to be that since non-double types were added later for specific uses, Matlab assumes a non-double array was created for a purpose and should remain that non-double type it was created as, regardless of any operation involving doubles.  Which makes sense in a way. @Alex

Comment: @TroyHaskin Thanks for the info! I have been bitten by that so many times particularly when trying to concatenate integers and doubles. I feel like there should (at the least) be a warning when you perform the concatenation.